# How to fix the relative positions of a subset of vertices in a network/graph in ggraph R package?

Tags: r, graph-theory, igraph, directed-graph, ggraph

I'm graphing several directed networks in `R` using the packages `igraph` and `ggraph` and need to be able to fix the relative positions of 4-6 vertices, depending on the network being graphed. The rest of the vertices (100+) will essentially form star graphs around these fixed vertices.

Here is an example of the type of graph that I would like to end up with:

[image]

What's important to me is that vertices A to D are arranged in the order shown in the photo and that the positions of vertices v1 to v7 are arranged to minimize crossing arcs.

I know that you can manually specify the positions of each vertex in `ggraph` using `create_layout()` and modifying the `x` and `y` values in the dataframe that is returned by `create_layout()`. (This is how I created the graph in the photo above and the code for it is below).

But manually specifying the vertex positions is time-consuming, so I'm looking for an alternative solution.

For example, is it possible to first manually specify the positions of vertices A-D and then somehow use an algorithm to determine the positions of the other vertices?

Phrased another way, how can I get from `graph` to  `customGraph` (or something similar; see code below) without having to manually specify all vertex coordinates?

Here's reproducible code with the example network I've been referring to:

```
# Create dataframe -------------------------------------------------------------

arcList <- data.frame(from = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v3', 
                               'v4', 'v5', 'v6', 'v7'),
                      to   = c('B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'A',   'A', 'A', 'B', 
                               'B', 'C', 'D', 'D'))

# Create network ---------------------------------------------------------------

network <- arcList %>% 
  graph_from_data_frame(directed = TRUE)

# Graph network ----------------------------------------------------------------

# plot network with a preset layout (ex. kamada-kawai)
graph <- ggraph(network, layout = 'kk') +
  geom_edge_fan(arrow = arrow(length = unit(2, 'mm'))) +
  geom_node_point() + 
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name), repel = TRUE)
graph
  
# create layout with a preset layout (ex. kamada-kawai; x, y positions correspond
#                                         to the vertex positions in `graph`)                                      
customLayout <- create_layout(network, layout = 'kk') 

# manually change node positions
customLayout$x <- c(-1, 0, 0, -1.4, -1.4, -1.3, 0.5, -0.5, 1.4, 1.4, 1)
customLayout$y <- c(0,  1, -1, 0.5, -0.5, 1,   0.9, -0.9, 0.5, -0.5, 0)

# plot network with custom layout
customGraph <- ggraph(customLayout) +
  geom_edge_fan(arrow = arrow(length = unit(2, 'mm'))) +
  geom_node_point() + 
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name), repel = TRUE)
customGraph
```